# Archive::Tar module backs up files and folders, but not files in folders

Tags: perl, archive

### Basic Problem.

I want to use Perl's Archive::Tar module to backup things.  I am tying to use `Archive::Tar` to back up files and folders and files in folders.  With my current code, the first two work, but the third doesn't.

### Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a sample directory.
2. In the sample directory, create two directories and a .txt file.
3. Using vim, write whatever in the .txt file.
4. In one of the directories in the sample directory, repeat steps two and three.
5. In the sample directory, create a perl script.
6. Copy the code below into the script.
7. Run the script.  In the box, type the names of the .txt file and the two directories.
8. Press the big compress button.
9. Open the new .tbz file in the compressed directory.

### Code.

```
use strict; use warnings;

use Archive::Tar;
use Tk;

my $mw = MainWindow -> new;
$mw -> Label ( -text => "Please type the files you wish to backup, separated by spaces." ) -> pack;

my $inputEntry = $mw -> Entry ( -width => 30 );
$inputEntry -> pack;

$mw -> Button ( -text => "Compress!", -command => sub { compress() } ) -> pack;

MainLoop;

sub compress {
    my $input = $inputEntry -> get;
    my @input;
    unless ( $input !~ m/ / ) {
        @input = split ( m/ /, $input );
    } else {
        @input = ( $input );
    }
    Archive::Tar -> create_archive ( "TEST.tbz", COMPRESS_BZIP, @input )    
}
```

Comment: Iirc, you have to explicitly list each file. Just passing a directory doesn't automatically recursively include everything in that directory.

Comment: Ah.  I think I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your steps to reproduce aren't clear and more examples could be helpful, but your script seems to work fine for me. I was able to add both folders and files, and files within folders successfully to the archive. For each file within a folder, I had to type the entire relative path eg. 'sample/file1.txt'.

You may be looking for a way to add the files within a folder automatically. Something like this would do the trick:

```
use strict; use warnings;

use Archive::Tar;
use Tk;

my $mw = MainWindow -> new;
$mw -> Label ( -text => "Please type the files you wish to backup, separated by spaces." ) -> pack;

my $inputEntry = $mw -> Entry ( -width => 30 );
$inputEntry -> pack;

$mw -> Button ( -text => "Compress!", -command => sub { compress() } ) -> pack;

MainLoop;

sub compress {
    my $input = $inputEntry -> get;
    my @input; 
    my @dirfiles;
    unless ( $input !~ m/ / ) {
        @input = split ( m/ /, $input );
    } else {
        @input = ( $input );
    }

    foreach(@input) { if(-d $_) { push(@dirfiles,glob "'${_}/*'"); } }
    push(@input,@dirfiles);

    Archive::Tar -> create_archive ( "TEST.tbz", COMPRESS_BZIP, @input )
}
```

I think there are still remaining issues, such as: This script appears to fail on files/folders with spaces in their names, even when escaped or quoted.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked!  Could you explain what the added line does, so that I can learn from my mistakes?

Comment: Thank you for the check mark. `There are three added lines. The first creates another local array (@dirfiles), the second grabs a list of files from any entry it detects is a folder and 'saves' that to the @dirfiles array. The third line merges the @dirfiles array with the '@input' array.`   You may find more information about perl glob here: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html

Comment: this will only get files directly in a folder, not files in a folder in the folder; for that you want File::Find